# Duplicate "Published to" Entries

Tags: 2011, publishing, cme

When looking at "Where used" and "Published to" for an item, we are seeing duplicate entries for the same Target. We are not able to remove the duplicates.

When unpublishing, these duplicate entries remain.

When republishing, a new duplicate entry is created.

[image: where used published to tab]

Any idea what could be causing this? Any way to remove them? I am ok with CoreService, but it looks like an internal set for this entry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I remember that we also faced the similar issue.

There is a hotfix available with ***customer support***, they give a SQL query related to `publish states` which needs to be run on the database.

Comment: I have gotten HotFix CM_2011.1.0.77065 from support and I am implementing it now...Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I have implemented the HotFix above. It appears to have fixed the issue of the duplication. I had to do some work with the TOM.COM to reset the status of the duplicate page entries. Glad the inter-op its still around.

Answer (score 2):

Please use Hotfix CM_2011.1.0.77065 if your system is Tridion 2011 SP1.

Note that the SQL script included in the hotfix may also run against a 2011 SP1 HR1 database (as it did in my system) but there is no guarantee the script may alter other data.

I would recommend checking with Customer Support just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

This usually results when a publish target was published to, then the pub target settings changed, while items remained in the published state for that target.

You can go into the CM DB and delete the records referring to your dangling pub target, but this isn't a supported approach. You should get the official script from Support to do this.